# Stokes' Theorem - The normal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Stokes' theorem says:
$$\oint_cFdr = \int\int_S curl F dS = \int\int_S curl F \cdot n \, dS$$

Where $F$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$. My question is what do I take $n$ to be?

If we parameterize a given region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of $r(u,v)$, do I take $n$ as:

$$n= r_u \times r_v \,or \,\, \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|} $$

Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a differnce, for the unit normal provides the orientation at a point, so it's length must be 1

$$n= \,\, \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|} $$

as

$$ n*dS= \,\, \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|} *dS = \,\, \frac{r_u \times r_v}{|r_u \times r_v|} *{|r_u \times r_v|}*dudv$$
$$ n*dS = {r_u \times r_v}*dudv$$
Differential forms aleviate much stress, with intrinsic orientation.

F=(P,Q,R)^t

$\int_S F dS = \int_S Pdy\wedge dz + \int_S Qdz\wedge dx + \int_S Rdx\wedge dy $

$dx\wedge dy = $ determinant of the 2x2 derivative matrix of x,y with respect to u,v

(which can be imagined as a projection of the determinant of the (entire) derivative matrix onto the x,y plane)

http://www.physics.oregonstate.edu/coursewikis/GDF/book/gdf/start

Is a good resource, a short wiki-book, which also answers your question in the first chapter I think.